# Add title attribute to replaced image

Tags: jquery

trying add the fdb.name as a title attribute to the images i used to replace the text that was showing. I used title="fdb.name" , but ofc that just displays that text and not to correct corresponding name from the database

```
(function($) {
for (var i = 1; i <= 96;  i++) {

    var fdb = null;

    if ( i < 10 ) {
        fdb = franchiseDatabase['fid_000' + i];
    } else {
        fdb = franchiseDatabase['fid_00' + i];
    }

    $('#brief_standings , #livescoring_summary ,#recent_draft_picks ')
    .find('td').filter(function() { return $(this).text() == fdb.name; })
    .html( '<a href="' + window.baseURLDynamic + '/' + window.year + '/options?L=' + window.league_id + '&F=' + fdb.id + '&O=01">' + '<img src="' + fdb.icon + '"class="franchiseicon" title="fdb.name" /></a>' );
}
```

Comment: <img src="#" class="franchiseicon" title="view teampage" />

Comment: You're doing it correctly for `fdb.id` and `fdb.icon`. How are you getting confused on `fdb.name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be like this if you want to do this using jQuery.

```
$("#"+this.id).attr("title", fdb.name);
```

Comment: edited my script to explain needs better , it is jquery , just didn't include it all sorry

Comment: Can you work with my updated answer? Not sure if my selectors are correct but you know your HTML better so I think you can get the selector right.

Answer (score 0):

You are duplicating the quotes. Try with this:

```
  .html( '<a href="#"><img src="#" class="franchiseicon" title="view teampage" /></a>' );
```

Answer (score 0):

In jquery you can use the setter for attributes attr(name,value) explained in http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2